# How to build docker images for windows using VS2017 and Docker integration?

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2016, docker-image

I'm working on Visual studio and Docker integration, but after working with some sample projects I realized that I can only build docker images for linux but not for windows. Is there any way to build docker images for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2017, you can target .NET FX using Console or ASP.NET apps with Windows Server Core containers. With the preview channel of Visual Studio 2017 (https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) you can now support .NET Core on Windows Nano containers as well.
Steve

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve Lasker. Is there any video link that you could share which helps working with Visual studio2017 & windows container